# Adding top and bottom border to a group of selected elements using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have a grid of search results. These results are selectable and when they are selected, I add the `class='selected'` to them.

There can be multiple groups of results (accomplished by command/ctrl-clicking rows). By groups of results what I mean is consecutive elements that are selected. What I want to do is, add a top border to only the first of any given group of selected results, and a bottom border to only the last item of a given group.

Is there a good way to do this with CSS? Or am I going to have to apply `.first` and `.last` within each group?

For example, consider this approximate HTML (row count doesn't totally match up):

```
<ul>
    <li>Gray row</li>
    <li class="selected">Blue row - should have border-top-color only</li>
    <li class="selected">Blue row - should have NO border-top-color or border-bottom-color</li>
    <li class="selected">Blue row - should have border-bottom-color only</li>
    <li>Gray row</li>
    <li>Gray row</li>
    <li class="selected">Blue row - should have border-top-color and border-bottom-color</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I want it to look like. This was faked in Chrome Devtools.

[image: faked visual of what it should look like]

Comment: I don't know what are you asking...

Comment: Without the HTML, CSS (and I presume JS) there's not much we can offer.

Comment: @AndrewParisi: I felt the question was pretty clear already but since it got closed with users feeling that it wasn't clear, I've edited the title and content in an attempt to make it clear. Please feel free to rollback if you think any part of the edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a combination of selectors like in the below snippet. While the below snippet shows that it is possible, I would still recommend using classes because I am sure you would be having JS to add the classes during Ctrl + Click.

Here are what the selectors in the snippet do:

- `.selected` - Adds a `border-top` to each element with the required `selected` class.
- `.selected + .selected` - Nullifies `border-top` if the `selected` element has another element with `selected` class immediately preceding it.
- `.selected + :not(.selected)` - Adds a `border-top` to every element which does not have the `selected` class but has an element with `selected` class preceding it. This acts like the `border-bottom` for the group.
- `.selected:last-child` - This is for the edge cases where the `last-child` is the one which has the `selected` class. In this case the previous selector will not apply and hence bottom border for the group will go missing.

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #DBEAF7;
  border-top: 1px solid #9FC5F8;
}
.selected + .selected {
  border-top: none;
}
.selected +:not(.selected) {
  border-top: 1px solid #9FC5F8;
}
.selected:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9FC5F8;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i tried this way..

```css
li.selected {
  background-color: #DBEAF7;
  border-top: 1px solid #9FC5F8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9FC5F8;  
}
.selected{
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.selected + .selected{
    border-top:none;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
  <li class="selected">Rejected</li>
  <li>Processed</li>
</ul>
```

and here is the working demo fiddle

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2nnvz9um/1/)**

Comment: @AndrewParisi please check out the answer