# How to target the first of a certain class in a ul li using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="container"></li>
    <li class="container"></li>
    <li class="container"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to create a top- and bottom-border on the `container` class elements, but only the first and last must have this border.

I tried to use CSS for this, but the `first-child` and `last-child` selectors do not do what I was expecting:

CSS:

```
.container:first-child {
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.container:last-child {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically add top- and bottom-borders with just these classes using CSS?

Comment: there can be a way to achieve this without nth- nor :first, ... i cannot give the answer to the duplicate since the case is different but: if this answers your question http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/reOqNo , it  might be possible to answer and unmarked your question here

Comment: You could also have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152053/adding-top-and-bottom-border-to-a-group-of-selected-elements-using-css/33152261#33152261). it is pretty similar to what you need (and GCyrillus' demo above). I thought of using this for dupe closure but BoltClock's answer in the other one was way more informative and so used that.